# How to delete all files and folders under C:/Users/testuser using python on windows

Tags: python, windows

I need a Python script to delete the complete user folder under `C:/Users` folder on windows.
I tried below code but I am getting errors for few files :

```
[WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:/Users/test\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Windows\\UsrClass.dat'
```

Note : On windows I am logged in with user A as admin and trying to delete user B folder. Before deleting user folder I am deleting registry entry using this command : `reg.exe", "delete", f"HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\ProfileList\\{profile}`

Below is the Pyhton code that I tried:

```
import os
import shutil
profile_folder_path = "C:/Users/test"
for base_dir, dirs, files in os.walk(profile_folder_path):
    for file in files:
        try:
            print(os.path.join(base_dir, file))
            os.chmod(os.path.join(base_dir, file), 0o777)
            os.remove(os.path.join(base_dir, file))
        except Exception as ex:
            print(f"Can not delete file: {ex}")
    for folder in dirs:
        try:
            print(os.path.join(base_dir, folder))
            os.chmod(os.path.join(base_dir, folder), 0o777)
            # os.rmdir(os.path.join(base_dir, folder))
            shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(base_dir, folder))

        except Exception as ex:
            print(f"Can not delete folder: {ex}")
```

I expected to delete complete user folder : `C:/Users/testuser`
My objective is to delete unused users and their user data folder on windows.

Comment: Hello @iron I thought Powershell would have some commands to achieve this.

Comment: I found a Powershell command to achive this : Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_UserProfile | Where {$_.LocalPath -eq 'C:\Users\test'} | Remove-CimInstance -Verbose -Confirm:$false

Answer (score 1):

I have made some modifications to your code, which is working on my laptop.

```
import os
import shutil
import subprocess

def terminate_processes(username):
    try:
        subprocess.run(["taskkill", "/F", "/IM", f"{username}.exe"], check=True, capture_output=True)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(f"Error terminating processes: {e.stdout.decode()}")

def delete_user_profile(user_folder_path):
    try:
        shutil.rmtree(user_folder_path)
        print(f"Deleted profile folder: {user_folder_path}")
    except Exception as ex:
        print(f"Failed to delete profile folder: {ex}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    target_username = "test"  
    profile_folder_path = os.path.join("C:/Users", target_username)
    terminate_processes(target_username)
    delete_user_profile(profile_folder_path)
```

Comment: Why would there be an "{username}.exe" running?

Answer (score 0):

Once you've established that none of the files in the relevant directory are in use then just do a recursive delete of the directory:

```
from shutil import rmtree
from pathlib import Path

DIR = '/Users/FOO'

if (directory := Path(DIR)).is_dir():
    try:
        rmtree(directory)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
else:
    print(f'{DIR} is not a directory')
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a Powershell command to achive this :

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_UserProfile | Where {$_.LocalPath -eq 'C:\Users\test'} | Remove-CimInstance -Verbose -Confirm:$false
```